# Why is the configuration of connectionstring readonly?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, connection-string

Sorry for the many asked question again, but i have not found a answer for solving my problem.
First of all:
I have a Web (customer-intranet, internal use only) where the user should decide, witch project should be shown. Every project has a connection to a database on different servers. So I have to change the connectionstring to the right database or I have to install the same web twice or more.
I cannot use different connectstring-names, because the the dataset-designer stores the connectionname hardcoded in the c#-designer-code.

Is there really now way, to set the project-connectionstring maybe in the global.asax.cs?
Or another way to handle this?

Comment: are you using Linq To SQL or EF?

Comment: Not shure, what you mean. we create a Dataset-class in the App_Data-Folder with contextmenu 'Add->Class' and its not the LinqToSql-Class

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could change the designer code to not hard code the connection name?

Why not add a method somewhere called `GetConnectionStringName()` which is called by the designer and will dynamically pick the correct connection string?

Comment: becouse code ist overwritten everytime, the designer is called and the code is created.

Comment: How is the connection string name being defined in the first place? Is it a property of the DataSet control?

Comment: That's all in the designer-created code. I don't know, when the code is accessed and the connection will opened.

Answer (score 1):

I just edit the C#-designer-code and replace it with a reference to the configuration manager connection string reference (or whatever floats your boat). It's generated automatically, that doesn't mean you can't edit it.

Comment: I know, I could edit the designed code. That's not only me, who create webpages. And everytime something changed in the dataset-layout the code has to edit again. That's no option

Answer (score 0):

@Hunter
Not shure, what you mean. we create a Dataset-class in the App_Data-Folder with contextmenu 'Add->Class'

@drachenstern
I know, I could edit the designed code. That's not only me, who create webpages. And everytime something changed in the dataset-layout the code has to edit again. That's no option

@Nathan Taylor
That's all in the designer-created code. I don't know, when the code is accessed and the connection will opened.